# SQL server 08 Limitations

Tags: shapefile, vector, sql-server

The Soil SURvey GeOgraphic (SSURGO) database is a set of very large and complicated shapefiles.  We want to load all of the shapefiles for the US into a national SQL database.

Are there import limitations for SQL 2008 for Spatial?

Also, are there any websites that use a SQL database for interactive thematic mapping?

Thanks

Bernie

Comment: is Microsoft a limitation? - There are no 'import' limitations - Do you have to use SQL Server 2008?

Comment: No, Microsoft is not a limitation. Yes, we have to use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: It might help to split this question up and repost as separate questions.  Each one is relevant to GIS, but could be expanded upon with additional detail based on your specific project needs.  In addition, you may be able to answer the 2nd question related to `Thematic mapping`, by doing a search on GIS.se.  You will likely find a few examples.  If not, then posting it as a separate question will hopefully garner relevant answers that will be useful to a wider audience.